# Navigation Link SwiftUI MVVM

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a toolbar with a button that should take me to a new view via NavigationLink like so:

```
.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                let vm = viewModel.add()
                NavigationLink("", destination: Add(viewModel: vm))
                    .buttonStyle(AddButtonStyle())
            }
         }
```

with the viewModel add function simply returning a viewModel for the Add view. I have this similar functionality elsewhere in my code and it works perfectly, but here the view never spawns. I did some debugging and the init for the AddViewModel is being executed repeatedly. But I can't figure out why the Add View is never spawning, and I am stuck on the previous screen.

Comment: It is never safe to create objects in the body

Comment: do you have NavigationView above this view?

Comment: in SwiftUI there is no need for view model objects thats what the View struct hierarchy, State and Binding are for.

Answer (score 0):

I write this simple code and it's work good. Can you add more information?

```
class ViewModel {
    func add() -> AddViewModel {
        AddViewModel()
    }
}

class AddViewModel { }

struct AddButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Circle().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
}

struct Add: View {
    let viewModel: AddViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    let vm = viewModel.add()
                    NavigationLink("", destination: Add(viewModel: vm))
                        .buttonStyle(AddButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NavigationView is deprecated, Apple recommends to use NavigationStack.

Comment: It depends on the minimum ios version of the project, but you can always change NavigationView to NavigationStack and code work just as well